# How to improve processing time of large rolling window computation

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, rolling-computation

I have a large dataset, including about 100,000 entries. I am using the tibbletime package to create a rolling version of the DL.test function from the vrtest package.

I am using a rolling window (size=1000), leading to about 99,000 computations. The code looks like this:

```
#installing packages
install.packages("tibbletime")
install.packages("vrtest")

#importing libraries
library(vrtest)
library(dplyr)
library(tibbletime)
library(tibble)

#generating demo data
data <- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(0:1,1010,rep=TRUE)))
names(data)[names(data) == "replicate.1..sample.0.1..1010..rep...TRUE.."] <- "log_return"

#running DL.test once
DL.test(data, 300, 1)

#creating a rolling window version of DL.test
test <- rollify(DL.test, window=1000, unlist=FALSE)

#applying function and saving results
results <- dplyr::mutate(data, test = test(log_return))
```

The issue now is that running DL.test even once takes a little less than 5 minutes on my current setup. Having to repeat this step nearly 100,000 times limits the practicality fairly strong.

What options do I have to speed this process up?

My current idea would be to create **many** smaller versions of my original dataset (e.g., entries 1 - 1500 for the first 500 computations, 501 - 2000 for the second batch...) and somehow employ parallel processing.

Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: Looking at the source code of `DL.test` it should be easy to reimplement with Rcpp. Since that function is your bottleneck, I don't see any other reasonable options.

Comment: @Roland thanks for your input! I already looked at the function's syntax for a while, but I have no deeper understanding of R. Could you give me some further hints on what to do/try next?

Comment: Do you have some basic understanding of C++? Otherwise you are stuck unless someone just does it for you.

Comment: Alright, seems like I will have to look for external support. Is there any way to gauge how fast the function might run after reimplementing it?

Comment: I'd say it would be faster by some orders of magnitude...